# Execute a query, use value as a variable and run another query and then print it?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

I've two tables, `users` and `coach_to_trainee`. User can have multiple coaches, and the data is stored in `coach_to_trainee` columns `coach_id` and `trainee_id`.

I'm using `coach_to_trainee` table to print out data for the user, so he/she can simply see who is his/her coach.

```
<?php
              $user = $_SESSION['login']['id'];
              $q = "SELECT * FROM coach_to_trainee WHERE trainee_id='$user'";
              $coachid = $db->prepare($q);
              $coachid->execute();

              while($row = $coach->fetchObject()){
                $coachid = $row->coach_id;
                echo '<li><a href="?coach&id='.$coachid.'">'.INSERT_COACH_NAME.'</a></li>';
              }


              ?>
```

However, this will only return the ID of the coach, and I need to return the name also, from table `users`.

How I'm supposed to do another query inside `while()` and use $coachid to find the correct user?

Comment: why don't you actually prepare your query? Why don't  use prepared statements?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tought that I'm using them? I started using pdo about 2 weeks ago so I've no idea if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587

Comment: @YourCommonSense How does `$coachid = $db->prepare($q);` differ from `$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where id=?"); then?` What if someone would do drop table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `JOIN` mysql clause, like this one:

```
SELECT u.name, u.id 
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN coach_to_trainee ctt
        ON u.id = ctt.coach_id 
WHERE ctt.trainee_id = {$user}
```

You should be done with this one ;-)

Then in Your PHP use the selected values:

```
while($row = $coach->fetchObject()){
    echo '<li><a href="?coach&id='.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Next time I'll open my mysql manual instead of thinking difficult in php. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that $row->coach_id doesn't print anything, any ideas?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen It is `$row->coach_id` no more, since You edited the query it should be **`$row->id`** then!!!

Comment: Ah, I feel so stupid now! The whole join clause is pretty complicated to me.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen I have edited the answer (PHP part) to match the query. In this case You could do `SELECT u.name, u.id`, then call it like `$row->name` and `$row->id` or You could do `SELECT u.name, ctt.coach_id` and then it would be as before - `$row->coach_id` and `$row->name`.

Comment: Note: To secure your site against XSS, you should use `htmlspecialchars()` before you output a variable which can be influenced by the user. Or if an value has to be an integer you should cast it. In your example: `echo '<li><a href="?coach&id='.(int)$row->id.'">'. htmlspecialchars($row->name) . '</a></li>'`.

Comment: @Mogria is it even possible as I'm using pdo? And the statement is prepared?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Yes, this has nothing to do with SQL. Lets say an user enters the username `<script>alert(1)</script>`. Without using `htmlspecialchars()` the script would be executed. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Comment: yeah, but doesn't pdo pretty much block complicated scripts by quoting the userinput?